# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project

Tags: java, macos, maven-3, pom.xml

I have below project structure

- Project A

  -- Child Project X

  -- Child Project Y
- Project C

  -- Child Project Z

I tried to Build all the projects using **pom.xml**

I was able to create jar files for `Child Project X` and `Child project Y`.

`Child Project Z` dependent on `Child Project X` to compile, however when **pom.xml** is run it is throwing the below error:

> "Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile
>   (default-compile) on project ChildProjectZ Compilation failure:
>   Compilation failure:"

I'm using `Mac OS 10.8, Maven 3.0.5, java 1.7`

Comment: You have compilation errors in your code as the msg says "Compilation failure: Compilation failure"

Comment: I understand that, when i checked the code it is internally referring to jar file of Child Project X, pom.xml is working fine in Windows machine. the same pom.xml is not working in Mac